# setNumMapTasks(int) is undefined for the job type - Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am not able to add "job.setNumMapTasks(int)" to the driver for my MapReduce program.  When I try to add it, I get a compile error stating, "setNumMapTasks(int) is undefined for the job type".  However, I am able to add the reducer equivalent, "job.setNumReduceTasks(int)".  It would seem to me that if I can add one, I should be able to add the other.  Below is my driver.  Any suggestions are very welcome.

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = getConf();      
    Job job = new Job(conf, "PiCalc");        
    job.setJarByClass(PiCalc.class);            
    Path in = new Path(args[0]);
    Path out = new Path(args[1]);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
    job.setJobName("PiCalc"); 
    job.setNumMapTasks(20);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(10);
    job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);   
    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the number of map tasks for the job. The number of map tasks equals the number of blocks in the input file.

By default the number of reducers equals 1, unless explicitly specified.